# Listen all IP packets including ICMP, TCP and UDP?

Tags: sockets, networking, go, tcp

Specially in golang, there are interfaces like `net.ListenIP` and `net.ListenTCP`.

I'm wondering that, if process p1 `ListenIP(192.168.1.1)` and process p2 `ListenTCP(192.168.1.1:80)`, will all packets dest to 192.168.1.1 (no matter TCP or UDP) are intercepted by p1, and p2 will never accept a TCP connection?

Comment: Why not test it yourself? It shouldn't be difficult to set up.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Thanks. I've done the test and turns out p2 can still accept TCP connections. It's confusing.

Comment: https://www.opensourceforu.com/2015/03/a-guide-to-using-raw-sockets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the source code of `net.ListenIP()`:

```
// ListenIP listens for incoming IP packets addressed to the local
// address laddr.  The returned connection's ReadFrom and WriteTo
// methods can be used to receive and send IP packets with per-packet
// addressing.
func ListenIP(netProto string, laddr *IPAddr) (*IPConn, error) {
    net, proto, err := parseNetwork(netProto)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, &OpError{Op: "listen", Net: netProto, Source: nil, Addr: laddr.opAddr(), Err: err}
    }   
    switch net {
    case "ip", "ip4", "ip6":
    default:
        return nil, &OpError{Op: "listen", Net: netProto, Source: nil, Addr: laddr.opAddr(), Err: UnknownNetworkError(netProto)}
    }   
    fd, err := internetSocket(net, laddr, nil, noDeadline, syscall.SOCK_RAW, proto, "listen", noCancel)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, &OpError{Op: "listen", Net: netProto, Source: nil, Addr: laddr.opAddr(), Err: err}
    }   
    return newIPConn(fd), nil 
}
```

it creates a raw socket, on linux, an [`IPPROTO_RAW` socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html) is send only. TCP and UDP packets are never delivered to raw sockets, they are always handled by the kernel protocol stack. Copies of ICMP packets are delivered to a matching raw socket. All other packets destined for protocols that are not processed by a kernel subsystem are delivered to raw sockets.

Comment: Packets those can be handled by kernel tcp/ip stack (like tcp, udp) will be delivered to kernel stack, packets those can't be handled by kernel stack will be delivered to raw sockets. Am I understanding you right?

Comment: Almost, note that copies of ICMP packets are delivered to a matching raw socket. For example, you can call `net.ListenIP("ip4:icmp", laddr)` to get ICMP echo packets(ping request) but kernel has already send replies to the sender(by default).

Comment: If I want to intercept all packets (dested to an ip address or a network interface) so that other processes will never receive tcp or udp packets. Is that possible? Imaging I'm implementing a switch/router in userspace.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a [TUN device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) instead. That's really the only way to intercept all IP traffic.

You may use a library like https://github.com/songgao/water.